# Offline programs like Mozilla Seamonkey for Ubuntu

Tags: web-development

Does anybody know of a program I can use offline in Ubuntu to help develop web pages, something like Mozilla Sea monkey, but not requiring a internet connection as my internet is slow and un-reliable as it is teatherd from a phone.

Any suggestions are welcome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your html files in `/var/www/` go to your local ip and use the file name to specify what file you want to test. Use any web browser you want.

Some web servers you should take a look at.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp
sudo apt-get install apache2
```